# Update list of entities transactional method

Tags: java, hibernate

Will all the cars be black (in the database) after leaving the method?

```
@Transactional
public void test() {
    List<Car> cars = carDao.findAll();
    cars.forEach(car -> car.setColor("black"));
}
```

Comment: Did you take a minute to try it ?

Comment: What does it have to do with transactions? You probably want to ask - if an exception happened during one of these write operations, would it rollback i.e. would all the saved cars be rollbacked?  Now that's a different question and would depend on other configurations in your project.  We can talk about it, but first we need to know what do you really want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the elements in the List will be updated to "black" into your database after the method ends.
You're most probably looking for the answer of why is doesn't require any update or merge method call.

`@Transactional` makes it a transaction and at the end of the transaction, the changes are flushed into database since transactions must be committed or rollbacked at the end of a transaction.